# CollectionView CollectionCell segue to DetailView

Tags: ios7, xcode5, uicollectionview, uistoryboardsegue, uicollectionviewcell

In my CollectionView I display two “object types” in CollectionCells.  What I would like to do is when the user clicks on a cell, in the “didSelectItemAtIndexPath” determine the object selected and use “performSegueWithIdentifier” to segue to the appropriate DetailTableViewContoller to display the details of the “object”.

The way I have the setup is NavigationController segue (root) to MyCollectionView segue (push) to DetailTableView.  The CollectionCell in the MyCollectionView is configured to segue to the DetailTableView.

Starting simply, when I have the following code in place, select a cell in MyCollectionView it segues to the DetailTableView correctly but when I select the Back button in the DetailTableView it fails.

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath {
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MySegueIdentifier" sender:self];
}
```

I get the dreaded

```
[6313:a0b] nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar
[6313:a0b] Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. 
       Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.
```

If I comment out the performSegueWithIdentifier… line it segues correctly and the Back button in the DetailTableView works perfectly.

Similar code pattern works fine in TableViewController seque to DetailViewController.

Any suggestions?  Is it proper to set the segue up from the CollectionCell to the DetailViewController?

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out.  Having the segue at the cell is incorrect.  Setting it at the Controller level is correct.